# Woocommerce user defined product meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, frontend, cart

I was wondering if it where possible to allow users to fill in product meta using an input fields on the products page. The values of these input fields only have to be saved in that specific order.

I started using product attributes but I couldnt find a way of saving the inputs to the attributes, without affecting the global attributes of that product.

Currently i've created post meta fields, but I'm still stuck at the process of saving these values to the current order.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: [Product Add Ons](https://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons)

Comment: I've heard about the product add ons, but I'd like to solve my problems without plugins. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/

It does what you are asking for.

If you are more inclined to write your own code, then take a look at this answer from a year ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443698/1456997

Comment: I always like to write it myself, so I'll try that out as well. The plugin does exactly what I want thnx for your help!